# Is it a good idea to multi-thread a program that its main function is to read from the disk?

Tags: c++, multithreading, io, stream, bigdata

I am developing a program which reads multiple big pages from the disk and perform several range search. The program reads from several pages then writes the query results to an output page. I have to maintain the order of the output so it corresponds to the order of the input.

However, the program becomes very slow after multiple reads, I am thinking of using a multi-thread program to run several search at a time. I have 4-core Linux machine and I would like to have two threads of the program. Is it a good idea? and how can I maintain the order of the output file? locks won't help since I don't know which thread would finishes first.

If it is a good idea how can I do so?

Thanks

*Update: This must be done without the use of any kind of SQL libraries.*

Comment: Does the program spend more time reading the file or processing data? If reading, multiple cores won't help you. Getting multiple disks or an SSD might help.

Comment: Reading is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Threading is clearly a good idea in this case.
To mantain the order in the results I would use a mapReduce approach, you can find some good help using qtConcurrent module from Qt. 
The idea is that you take one or more pages and you pass them to a thread which will return the search results in a list.
Every thread/task is going to have a unique index so in the end the list returned from thread with index 2 will be placed after the list returned by thread with index 1.